# How To Stop & Prevent "Email Spoofing"?

Tags: email-server

Currently my server running on Windows 2003 with MERAK(IceWarp) Email Exchange install.

Email Spoofing happen across entire email domain network. How can I stop & prevent email spoofing happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 44 of the ["Anti Spam – Best Practices" IceWarp white paper](http://www.icewarp.com/downloads/whitepapers/Anti_Spam_Server_Side_Scanning_with_IceWarp.pdf) (PDF):

> To make certain that someone cannot
>   breach the system and send messages to
>   server accounts via the server domain
>   name, administrators should select the
>   option, “Reject if originators domain
>   is local and not authorized.” This
>   option prohibits spammers from
>   spoofing legitimate accounts such as
>   PostMaster and Admin, and will
>   eliminate uncertainty in the end user.